# useContext / createContext with TypeScript - Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-context

I read the article
[Application State Management with React](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react) from Kent C. Dodds.

I wanted to use TypeScript instead of JavaScript.

But I am failing with the following when I want to destruct the context

The application itself works. It is just an IDE error, but from my experience if there is an IDE error you should fix it.

It is about the following line

```
  const [count, setCount] = context
```

```
TS2488: Type 'number' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

[Code Sandbox to reproduce the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-context-typescript-example-gwi2t?file=/src/counter/counter-context.tsx)

Complete code:

count-context.tsx

```
import React, {createContext, useContext} from "react";

const initialState = 0

const CountContext = createContext(initialState)

function useCount() {
    const context = useContext(CountContext)
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error(`useCount must be used within a CountProvider`)
    }

    /*
     * This gives error
     * TS2488: Type 'number' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
     */
    const [count, setCount] = context

    const increment = () => setCount((c: number) => c + 1);
    const decrement = () => setCount((c: number) => c - 1);


    return {
        count, increment, decrement
    }
}

function CountProvider(props: any) {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(initialState)
    const value = React.useMemo(() => [count, setCount], [count])
    return <CountContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />
}

export {CountProvider, useCount}
```

page.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {CountProvider, useCount} from "./count-context";

function Counter() {
    const {increment, decrement} = useCount()

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={decrement}> Count down</button>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={increment}> Count up</button>
        </>
    )

}

function CountDisplay() {
    const {count} = useCount()
    return <p>The current counter count is {count}</p>
}


export function CountPage() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Count Page</h1>
            <CountProvider>
                <CountDisplay/>
                <Counter/>
            </CountProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on the same problem. Have you tried this

```
const {count, setCount} = context
```

instead of this

```
const [count, setCount] = context
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error makes sense since your initial state is of type number, while your provider accepts a tuple returned from `useState`, try:

```
type ContextType<S> = [S, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<S>>] | null;

const initialState = null;
const CountContext = createContext<ContextType<number>>(null);
```

[image: Edit Type context]

Comment: It feels wrong to me, and I am wondering why React is not doing that automatically. 

I also noticed that the array destructuring of createContext is not documented here

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext (in comparsion to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

Comment: It shouldn't mention any array destructing. It DEPENDS on what value you pass, in your case its a tuple. You haven't typed what the context accepts as mentioned.